# REST client HTTP multipart support

Tags: .net, http, multipart

I have a 3-rd party REST domain that requires doing HTTP multipart POST requests in order to create/update resources. Moreover, getting resource representation is done by a GET request where the response is expected to be a multipart HTTP (the multipart HTTP messages are used for 2 main purposes: 1 - attaching binary files to the resources representation, 2 - performing batch operations - each part in the multipart message is a sub-task of a composite task.

My question is: is there a .Net client library that supports both posting HTTP multipart requests and getting HTTP multipart responses?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to "throw your own" like with REST in general.

For `multipart/mixed` in particular, you have to supply as `boundary` to separate the different parts document parts. This boundary can only be chosen well, if you know exactly what the data you are getting looks like.